# How dou you create a dynamic pdf file?

Tags: pdf

I am trying to create a dynamic PDF file in my application. But what is the best practice to create a PDF with style and dynamic values, like the Newsletters you receive from big companies? I know you can use something like iTextSharp but I think it's difficult and much work to create an entire page with different style, images, colors, fonts, and more.
Are they using a HTML file and convert this into an PDF? Do they make some replacements in a string (for example: Your new e-mail is {{email}}) or are they using some custom solution for this problem?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what tech stack you are using. For example, in Ruby on Rails you can return a html template with embedded ruby for dynamic information and have something like pdfkit turn it into a pdf.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So this means, in Ruby on Rails the "best" or common practice is to have some embedded code, which fills the dynamic values and the result will be converted into a HTML file?
Does this mean, that you have a "smaller" program inside your program, sorry I don't have any expirience with it.